# App launched in play store giving security alert

Tags: visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova, google-play-developer-api, apache-cordova

We created a mobile app using "Tools for appache cordova for visual studio 2013 - CTP 3.1. The app is launched successfully in playstore. But in recent days when we login in our play store id, we receive a warning.

" **Security alert**
    *Your app is using a version of Apache Cordova containing one or more security vulnerabilities. Please see this Google Help Center article for details, including the deadline for fixing the app.
    Affects APK version 20300.*"

how do we solve this version we checked the cordova version in our system it shows 5.3 but the error still persists.

Answer (score 0):

Tools for Apache Cordova for Visual Studio 2013 CTP 3.1 is about a year old at this point. I'd recommend moving to Visual Studio 2015, which includes the latest version of these tools, as well as newer versions of Apache Cordova.

Using Visual Studio 2015, you can update your project to the latest version of Cordova (currently 6.1.0), which supports an updated version of Cordova-Android that might fix your security issue. More details here: http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2016/03/02/cordova-android-5.1.1.html

Comment: Is not it possible to get the work done in Visual Studio 2013 itself.